# How to split an integer into individual digits and then square each number?

Tags: java

I want to split an integer into digits and then raise each number to the power 2 and print that out. This is what I have:

```
int n = 666;
String number = String.valueOf(n);
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
    int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);
    Math.pow(j, 2);
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

The output is only the `666` number.

What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please include any errors or bad output you may have gotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you don't actually use the return value of `Math.pow()`.

[`Math.pow(x, 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) is one way to raise a number to the power of 2, but it is floating-point math, not integer math. Power of 2 means to multiply the number by itself, so `x * x` is much better.

```
int number = 299792458; // Speed of light in m/s
for (char ch : Integer.toString(number).toCharArray()) {
    int digit = ch - '0';
    System.out.println(digit * digit);
}
```

Or using Java 8 streams:

```
int number = 299792458; // Speed of light in m/s
Integer.toString(number)
       .chars()
       .map(c -> (c - '0') * (c - '0'))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4
81
81
49
81
4
16
25
64
```

Comment: Interesting solution, what's the purpose of the `- '0'` in the first one?

Comment: @LeonHorka A `char` is a Unicode character (the `c` in the stream version is a full Unicode code-point). Digits are the same in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), and the characters for `0` to `9` are consecutive, so subtracting `0` from the char value is a simple/fast way to say `Character.digit(ch,10)`. This of course assumes you're not using any of the alternative [digit characters in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), which `Character.digit()` would handle correctly. Not an issue with result of `Integer.toString()`.

Answer (score 4):

`Math.pow(j, 2)` doesn't modify `j`, it returns a new value.  You should capture the output of `Math.pow` to a variable and print that

Answer (score 1):

```
int m = n;
while (m > 0)
{
    int digit = m % 10;
    System.out.printf("%d\n", Math.pow(digit, 2));
    m /= 10;
}
```

Is this what you want?

---

Due to Andreas comment which said the order is reversed, I changed the code:

```
int length = number.length();
for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    int divisor = (int) Math.pow(10, i);
    int digit = n % divisor;
    System.out.printf("%d\n", Math.pow(digit, 2));
}
```

Also I could have written it as:

```
int length = number.length();
int divisor = (int) Math.pow(10, length - 1);
while (divisor > 0)
{
    int digit = n % divisor;
    System.out.printf("%d\n", Math.pow(digit, 2));
    divisor /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Returns digits in reverse order. May not be appropriate for OP's assignment.

Comment: What is `number`? If it is the String, then using the Strings digits would be faster than `Math.pow()`, so why complicate things like this? The purpose of using a `Math.pow()` implementation would be to eliminate the need for converting the number to String.

Comment: @Andreas I used `number.length()` to get length of the number to do calculations on parsed number; why do we need to use `charAt(i)` while we can `parse` `String` to `integer` and use simple mathematical operations?

Comment: The real input is `int n = 666`, not the value of the String `number`. There is no need to *parse* anything, so not sure what you are talking about. In your code, you rely of the formatting of `n` into a String, *just* so you can use the length, then you ignore the readily available digits in the string and jump through hoops to calculate them again. You second example even used `n`, while your third example incorrectly used `number`. Neither works or even compiles. First example compiles but fails with `IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double`.

Comment: Yes I had a mistake. I meant to write n % divisor but wrote number % divisor. Edited the answer. thanks

Comment: Still, none of your examples work. They are all suffering from the fact that `Math.pow()` returns a `double`, not an `int`.

Comment: a type cating is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print sq of individual digits.

```
int num = 666;
String number = String.valueOf(num);
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
    int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);
    int res = (int) Math.pow((double) j, (double) 2);
    System.out.println("digit: " + res);
}
```

Comment: No need to cast to `double`. Compiler will do that for you (See [JLS 5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)). Also, please fix your indentations.